# Windows XP hangs when loading on startup of VMware

Tags: imac

After total shutdown and restart of my iMac with VMware installed, I start VMware and it starts loading Windows XP Pro and then hangs in the middle of the Windows loading process.  The cursor disappears.  Repeated clicks on control-command keys will recover the cursor but it can only be used to close VMware.  I can't find any means to continue or complete the Windows loading.  Any suggestions?

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Did it EVER work?

Try [starting XP in safe mode](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/chsafe.htm#02) and see how it behaves (ie: does it load?).

If it loads then you know it's (probably) a driver issue.

Comment: Yes, it did work.  Thank you for your help.  I just wonder if I will run into this problem every time I shut down completely and have to reboot Windows XP.